# Apple TouchID - Detect authentication with newly added fingerprints

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, touch-id

I'm integrating TouchID into my app, for security reasons I need to block the user when he is trying to authenticate with newly added fingerprints [Which is added after enabling TouchID authentication in my app].

I can detect the biometry changes using **LAContext's** `evaluatedPolicyDomainState`. but this only says either biometric database was modified (fingers or faces were removed or added) or not.

Is there any other way I can find whether user has authenticated using newly added fingerprint
[added after enabling TouchID in my app] or not.

Any thoughts on this? appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to determine whether the biometric authentication took place with a "new" or "old" finger. This is a hardware limitation.

The biometric validation takes place in the [Secure Enclave](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/security/sec0f02a0f7f/1/web/1). The Secure Enclave simply returns a yes/no answer to the main processor. The main processor does not have any access to the actual biometric data that was validated.

You can, as you have noted, determine if the biometric database has been updated since you last evaluated the domain state.  The best you can do is invalidate all biometric access if you determine that the database has been modified, even if that modification was the removal of a finger.